# Android Studio to Firebase: register method not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i want create a login/register activity with firebase,
i connected the app with firebase console and i followed the instruction but it doesn't work

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fody.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

```
package com.fody.app;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    EditText editemail, editpassword;
    Button buttonLogin;
    String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin).setOnClickListener(this);

        editpassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editemail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }

    private void registerUser(){
        String email = editemail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editpassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(email.isEmpty()){
            editemail.setError("Inserire una mail");
            editemail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(password.isEmpty()){
            editpassword.setError("Inserire una password");
            editpassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            editemail.setError("Please enter a valid email");
            editemail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(password.length()< 6){
            editpassword.setError("Inserire una password di almeno 6 caratteri");
            editpassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, PersonalData.class));
                } else {

                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        });



    }

    private void openPersonalData() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,PersonalData.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonLogin:
                registerUser();
                break;


        }
    }


}
```

when i debug, my breakpoin come to mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() and go to the end
skipping everything. and off course is not registered

Comment: You can't step into the callback, as it is invoked asynchronously. Set a breakpoint **inside** `onComplete (i.e. on `if (task.isSuccessful()) {`) and then check what's happening.

Comment: i tried but it can't enter on insde breakpoint

Comment: Are you saying that `onComplete` never fires? The most common cause of that would be that you don't have an internet connection. I don't really know why else it wouldn't work, but hope someone else can chime in.

Comment: i thought also the same, but internet go, and i adeed to manifest perms to internet

Comment: Have you checked logcat for any error or exception?

Comment: yes i did, but after hours i found the problem, was about the AVD, google play servise was not updated, i solved thanks for all